# How to map secure.domain.com to www.domain.com or domain.com with "WordPress MU Domain Mapping" on the primary multisite domain?

Tags: redirect, domain-mapping, ssl

We have a multisite setup, the primary site needs to have `example.com`, `www.example.com` and `secure.example.com` mapped in wordpress so the primary site's content loads on them.

`secure.example.com` will be over HTTPS.

The problem we are facing is everything except `secure.example.com` works. When attempting to access `https://secure.example.com` there is a `302` redirect to: `http://www.example.com/wp-signup.php?new=secure.example.com`  `secure.domain.com` has a SSL Certificate to server secure content.  Obviously it can't just redirect otherwise it wouldn't be secure any longer.

WordPress MU Domain Mapping is installed but doesn't appear under the primary site's menus.  When trying to access the plugin directly via `~/wp-admin/tools.php?page=domainmapping` we recieve the message

> "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

Note: We are logged in as Super Admin.

Any suggestions regarding to this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The domain mapping page will only be visible under Network admin > Settings `/wp-admin/network/settings.php?page=dm_admin_page` unless the "User domain mapping page" option is selected.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified.  This occurs when I try going under the primary site in the network's admin area, logged in as super admin.  It's wierd because the other sites in the network show the Domain Mapping page, but the primary site does not.

Comment: you can't map the primary site to another domain, only sub-sites.

Comment: I just need to map/mirror secure.domain.com to the primary site so order forms are over ssl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended using mod_rewrite through .htaccess.  The following is what I am using and so far is working well.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secure\.domain\.net$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.net/$1 [P,L]
```